# how do I change the url of my site before unload?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, onbeforeunload, window.location

So I have a page that is navagated through by clicking on tabs that change what is displayed in the body of the website, and when you go to a new tab (in the site) it changes the url. e.g I'm in the home tab, and the url is changed to `https://a.website.com/home`, then i go to the changelog tab, and the url is changed to `https://a.website.com/changelog`. niiether of these urls actually exist, so how would I make it so when the user reloads they are directed to `https://a.website.com`, not to a page not found error page?
possibly using `window.onbeforeunload`?

Comment: "when the user reloads" do you mean when they press the browser "Reload this page" button or key-combination? Or do you mean something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark the tab that is being used as a parameter of the page:

```
https://a.website.com?tab=home
https://a.website.com?tab=changelog
```

Then, on your page you can decide which tab to show.